# Integrate $\int \frac{\sin^2x}{1 + \cos x}\,\mathrm dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't know how to start this integration problem:

> $$\int \frac{\sin^2x}{1 + \cos x}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Do you know a trig identity between sin(x) and cos(x)?. Do you know the difference of 2 squares?

Answer (score 11):

It is

$$ \frac{\text{sin}^2(x)}{1+\text{cos}(x)} =\frac{1-\text{cos}^2(x)}{1+\text{cos}(x)} = \frac{(1-\text{cos}(x))(1+\text{cos}(x))}{1+\text{cos}(x)}=1-\text{cos}(x)$$

and because of this

$$ \int \frac{\text{sin}^2(x)}{1+\text{cos}(x)} \ \text{d}x =\int1-\text{cos}(x) \ \text{d}x= x -  \text{sin}(x) + const.$$